# Decode of base64 string containing zip file gets 8 character codes wrong in result string

Tags: java, character-encoding, zip, base64, decode

I'm receiving a base64-encoded zip file (in the form of a string) from a SOAP request.
I can decode the string successfully using a stand-alone program, b64dec.exe, but I need to do it in a java routine.  I'm trying to decode it (*theZipString*) with Apache commons-codec-1.7.jar routines:

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;  
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.StringUtils;
StringUtils.newString(Base64.decodeBase64(theZipString), "ISO-8859-1");
```

Zip file readers open the resulting file and show the list of content files but the content files have CRC errors.

I compared the result of my java routine with the result of the b64dec.exe program (using UltraEdit) and found that they are identical with the exception that eight different byte-values, where ever they appear in the b64dec.exe result, are replaced by 3F ("?") in mine.  The values and their ISO-8859-1 character names are A4 ('currency'), A6 ('broken bar'), A8 ('diaeresis'), B4 ('acute accent'), B8 ('cedilla'), BC ('vulgar fraction 1/4'), BD ('vulgar fraction 1/2'), and BE ('vulgar fraction 3/4').

I'm guessing that the StringUtils.newString function is not translating those eight values to the string output, because I tried other 8-bit character sets: UTF-8, and cp437.  Their results are similar but worse, with many more 3F, "?" substitutions.

Any suggestions?  What character set should I use for the newString function to convert a .zip string?  Is the Apache function incapable of this translation?  Is there a better way to do this decode?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

A zip file is *not* a string. It's *not* encoded text. It may contain text files, but that's not the same thing. It's just binary data.

If you treat arbitrary binary data as a string, bad things *will* happen. Instead, you should use streams or byte arrays. So this is fine:

```
byte[] zipData = Base64.decodeBase64(theZipString);
```

... but *don't* try to convert that to a string. If you write out that `byte[]` to a file (probably with `FileOutputStream` or some utility method) it should be fine.

Comment: Thanks.  That fixes the substituted byte-value problem.

Comment: Thanks.  That fixes the substituted byte-value problem.
I have one remaining issue:  theZipString has a 0D0A line terminator after every 64 characters.  The Base64.decodeBase64 function leaves a 0A byte after every 48th byte in the decoded byte[] (corresponding to the encoded line).  Is there a way to configure Base64.decodeBase64 to leave the A0s out?

Comment: @user2200046: I would look at the base64 library at http://iharder.net/base64 - but it's also possible that whatever's *encoding* it is broken.

Comment: All set.  The extra 0As were artifacts of my test configuration.
Thanks!

Comment: I am facing a similar problem but its not working in my case. I have tried all, but it doesn't seem to work. Can you please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15630096/zip-file-corrupt-fetching-from-soap-attachment It would be lot of help!!

Comment: @PriyanshuJha: Your problem really isn't similar. This problem was with base64 data - there's no indication that base64 is involved in your problem.

Comment: I'm sorry for terming it similar, but i suspect that my problem has something related to encoding. The stream i am getting is either 7-bit encoded or Quote-printable encoded. That's why i though you might be able to look into it!!

Comment: Is it ok to take a byte array and convert to base64 String like this? `DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(byteArray)`?

Comment: The reason I ask is because I have to take an uploaded zip file and convert it's contents into a base64 encoded String for a 3rd party lib

Comment: @ZackMacomber: it sounds like you should be asking a new question, specifying exactly what you're concerned about. It's not really about *decoding* base64 which is what this question concerns.