# ZIP file corrupt fetching from SOAP attachment

Tags: java, soap, zip, saaj

I am using a web service that helps me to fetch files from a message hub.
File type can either be XML or ZIP.

For ZIP files, the content type is binary.

I have this piece of code :

```
private String extractPayload(String filePath, AttachmentPart attach){

        FileOutputStream fileStream = null;

        try {
              DataHandler handler;
              handler = attach.getDataHandler();

              File f = new File(filePath);

              fileStream = new FileOutputStream(filePath);

              handler.writeTo(fileStream);

              fileStream.flush();

        } catch (Exception ex) {

              logger.info("####Exception:" + ex.getMessage());

        } finally {

              if (fileStream != null)
                    fileStream.close();

        }

        return filePath;
```

}

Now, the code works fine for fetching XML files, although, in case of ZIP files, the file turns out to be corrupt. 
I downloaded the same file using file utility from the Messaging Hub and found out that the Size of File that i fetch through SOAP Attachment is around 4 bytes more then its actual size.

**Update :** The attachment encoding is 7-Bit (if that might be obstructing) while another attachment containing another zip is encoded Quote-printable. Both the zips are being fetched from same web service (although they differ in encoding), and both turn out corrupt.

**Edit:** I strongly feel that the problem is with the encoding in which i am receiving file and here is a comparison between the actual file and the received attachment file.

Actual File size : 9031 bytes
Received Attachment File size : 9066 bytes

I tried comparing both files in a document editor to find the differences between both.
Original file to fetched attachment file differences (Binary editor):

ed changed to 3f ,
db changed to 3f ,
d6 changed to 3f ,
85 changed to 3f ,
d0 changed to 3f ,

and so on.

Zip file contains a PDF and an XML file.

The start line of both files are similar, starting with PK

Answer (score 3):

I assume your `buf` is a 2048 bytes array. Try the following change

Replace

```
fileStream.write(buf);
```

with this

```
fileStream.write(buf, 0, n);
```

This is to fix in case in your last read you get only 1024 bytes then the other 1024 bytes of the `buf` will have garbage values and will get written to file and will corrupt it.

Comment: I think you mean `write(buf, 0, n)` - but the premise is correct.

Comment: Tried already. The problem is, zis.read() throws exception java.util.ZipException: Invalid block action.

Also, entry.getSize() (For getting Zip entry size) returns -1.

Comment: @PriyanshuJha: *Where* does it throw that? You should *at least* make the change which shazin talked about... because currently that's a very real bug.

Comment: @JonSkeet :   
I have fixed that bug. It throws exception at zis.read(). I had read somewhere that i can do a zis.read() to check if it getting a valid zip stream, if it returns -1 or throws an exception might mean that stream is not a valid zip stream. I also printed the attachment MIME types and the values are : MIME:Content-Type : application/binary MIME:Content-Transfer-Encoding : 7Bit I suspect that the content is not being sent in correct encoding!!

Comment: Need more information on your ZIP File. If the 7-Bit encoded then you better decode it first before trying to read it.

Comment: @PriyanshuJha: Yes, that sounds like the problem. I would get rid of the ZipInputStream part completely for now - just write out the raw data you're getting from `handler.getDataSource().getInputStream()` into a file, and compare that with the original zip file... then edit your question with the relevant information.

Comment: @JonSkeet i have done that. That was my 1st approach and later on i tried moving on to the Zis thing, but to no use.

I am editing question, adding more details to the difference between the two files.

Comment: @PriyanshuJha: If you knew there was already a difference, why did you start using `ZipInputStream`? Surely the *first* thing to do is make sure you can get the bytes correctly from A to B. *Then* you start interpreting those bytes as a zip file.

Comment: @JonSkeet I wasn't aware initially that a different encoding is being sent.
I thought, the stream might be being written wrongly than it is supposed to be and that's why I moved to ZIS (Naive mistake). Later on, when i was certain that there is some other issue, i delved further into the encoding type of stream and what ZIP is supposed to be, reaching to this point. I have updated the question to reflect my discoveries. This is the first time I am working with streams and so I am not too aware of different nuances. So, please excuse me for naive statements and actions.

Comment: @PriyanshuJha: Your post talks about *characters* - but a zip file is *binary* data. You shouldn't be trying to load it into a *text* editor to compare the original with the result. You should use a binary file editor. You should also give more information about the web service - is that under your control at all? Perhaps that's broken?

Comment: @JonSkeet No, the web service is from another organization. We just have their WSDL with us.
Its basically a message hub which stores files in form of messages and acts as middle party for data interchange. Previously, they had given a desktop application that did remote calls but was pretty slow to start with. Once they exposed Web services to us, we are now transitioning to use their web service. Their WSDL has no option to specify the encoding although you can specify content type. We specify content type as Binary.

Comment: @JonSkeet Also, a strange thing is that, when we fetch more messages, the encoding type is differing each time.
Meaning, i had 2 zips on hub, i made two calls. In the first call, the Encoding type is 7But while in the next call, it showed Quote-printable.

Comment: @PriyanshuJha: Sounds pretty ropy to me. I suggest you get in contact with that organization - it sounds like it's a pretty specific problem at their side.

Comment: @JonSkeet yeah, even i think its a problem from their side. Although, i have edited the question to reflect binary data changes, in case you wanna take a look.
I was an intern here and this project was given towards the fag end of internship. Today is my last day, i suppose i will have to leave it here.
Anyways!! Thanks for all the help extended!! and sorry for bothering you!!